# Como pegar as strings que estao entre colchetes?

Tags: php

Bom dia. Desde já agradeço..
Como posso pegar o conteúdo que esta dentro dos colchetes?

```
lang[en-US].php
lang[pt-BR].php
```

Na verdade é uma listagem de arquivos que esta dentro de uma pasta:

```
$atual = $ap . $dir . '/' . $file;
if(is_file($atual)) {
   echo '<li>'.$file.'</li>';
}
```

Porem quero que **`$file`**, que corresponde a ex: `lang[pt-BR].php`, imprima somente oque esta entre os colchetes. EX: **`pt-BR`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras.

**A que eu iria preferir, por ser mais pratico (=P):**

Usar o `explode`, que quebra a string onde determina.

```
<?php

$texto = 'lang[en-US].php';
// Seu $texto

$texto = explode('[', $texto);
// $texto agora possui: [0] => 'lang', [1] => en-US].php

$texto = explode(']', $texto[1]);
// $texto agora possui [0] => en-US, [1] => .php

echo $texto[0];
// Resultado: en-US
```

**STRISTR: Quero algo com menor número de linhas!**

Pode utilizar o `stristr`, que tem função similar ao `explode`, junto como `str_replace`.

```
$texto = 'lang[en-US].php';
$cortado = stristr(stristr($texto, '['), ']', true);

// Escolha um para remover os [:
$texto = str_replace('[', '', $cortado);
// OU
$texto = substr($cortado, 1);
```

**REGEX: Quero usar REGEX**

Porque REGEX é a regra de três da programação.

```
$texto = 'lang[en-US].php';
preg_match('/\[(.*?)\]/', $texto, $cortado);

// Escolha um para remover os []:
$texto = str_replace('[', '', str_replace(']', '', $cortado[0]));
// OU
$texto = substr($cortado[0], 1, -1); 
//OU
$texto = $cortado[1];
```

**Nota:**

> O `str_replace` pode ser trocad por `substr`.

Comment: VLWZÃO HEHEH ;)

Comment: Adicionei mais alternativas =P

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php):

**PHP**

```
$atual = $ap . $dir . '/' . $file;
preg_match('/\[(.*)\]/', $file, $matches);
if(is_file($atual)) {
    echo '<li>' . $matches[1] . '</li>';
}
```

**Explicação da expressão regular**

```
\[ encontra o caracter [ literalmente
    Primeiro grupo a ser capturado (.*)
        .* encontra qualquer caracter (exceto quebra de linha)
            Quantificador: * Entre zero à ilimitadas vezes
\] encontra o caracter [ literalmente
```

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gX4vQ7/1)**

-- EDIT --

Como o @Inkeliz apontou, existem várias formas de se chegar a solução. Pessoalmente, também utilizaria a solução do @Inkeliz :)

Vou deixar minha resposta apenas para se ter outra solução para o problema.

Comment: VLWZÃO HEHEH ;)