# Obter conteúdo entre marcações [x] e [/x] com Expressão Regular

Tags: php, regex

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, eu tenho o conteúdo abaixo que vem de uma tabela em um banco de dados e eu gostaria de usar uma expressão regular ou se tiver algo melhor, para separar apenas o conteúdo de dentro dos colchetes.

> `[pt-br]`
>
> Qual é Lorem Ipsum?
>
> Lorem Ipsum  é simplesmente texto manequim da impressão e composição
>   indústria. Lorem Ipsum tem sido o texto padrão do manequim da
>   indústria desde os anos 1500, quando uma impressora desconhecida tomou
>   uma galera de tipo e mexidos-lo para fazer um livro tipo espécime. Ele
>   sobreviveu não apenas cinco séculos, mas também o salto para
>   composição eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Foi
>   popularizado na década de 1960 com o lançamento de folhas Letraset
>   contendo Lorem Ipsum passagens, e mais recentemente com software de
>   editoração como Aldus PageMaker, incluindo versões de Lorem Ipsum.
>
> `[/pt-br]`

---

> `[en-us]`
>
> What is Lorem Ipsum?
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
>   five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>   remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
>   the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
>   more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
>   including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
>
> `[/en-us]`

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121285/como-pegar-as-strings-que-estao-entre-colchetes

Comment: Acredito que este "dentro dos colchetes" seja o conteúdo entre as tags `[pt-br]` e `[/pt-br]`, mas a ideia continua sendo a mesma.

Comment: bom, o conteúdo é [pt-br] conteúdo aqui [/pt-br] assim por diante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$texto = "[pt-br]

Qual é Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente texto manequim da impressão e composição 
indústria. Lorem Ipsum tem sido o texto padrão do manequim da indústria
desde os anos 1500, quando uma impressora desconhecida tomou uma galera 
de tipo e mexidos-lo para fazer um livro tipo espécime. Ele sobreviveu 
não apenas cinco séculos, mas também o salto para composição eletrônica,
permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Foi popularizado na década de 1960
com o lançamento de folhas Letraset contendo Lorem Ipsum passagens, e mais 
recentemente com software de editoração como Aldus PageMaker, incluindo
versões de Lorem Ipsum.

[/pt-br]";

$output = array();
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $texto, $output);
$texto = str_replace($output[0],'', $texto);
echo $texto;
```

<sub>**Exemplos:**</sub>

- [Ideone 1](http://ideone.com/84h10G)
- [Ideone 2](http://ideone.com/NSTz1P)

---

Separando em um `array`:

```
$output = array();
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $texto, $output);
$result = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($output[0]); $i = $i + 2)
{
    $ini = strripos($texto, $output[0][$i]);    
    $end = strripos($texto, $output[0][$i+1]);
    $result[str_replace(['[',']'],'',$output[0][$i])] = 
        str_replace($output[0],'', substr($texto, $ini, $end-$ini)); 

}

var_dump($result);
```

<sub>**Exemplo:**</sub>

- [Ideone 3](http://ideone.com/l1mC55)

Comment: esse reg aí vai pegar o [/pt-br] também? Porque aqui não pegou não.

Comment: @AsuraKhan sim pegou olha nos exemplos por favor!

Comment: Ahh tá agora sim.

Comment: @OsvaldoQueta eu fiz um edite, por favor verifique.

Comment: Que erro @OsvaldoQueta

Comment: @OsvaldoQueta não tem problema algum o código é esse mesmo, o <p> não vai causar nenhum problema, acabei de testar! olha [o link](http://ideone.com/6QQk5M)

Comment: O que tem de errado @OsvaldoQueta?

Comment: @OsvaldoQueta se está imprimindo o valor como? se você está usando var_dump poxa vida ta errado o jeito de programar;

Comment: Cara se ta programando errado. É com echo. Ta vendo !!! @OsvaldoQueta

Comment: @OsvaldoQueta o texto não esta como na pergunta, sem padrão pode acontecer isso.

Comment: Cole o texto que está lá gravado para mim ver @OsvaldoQueta tipo https://jsfiddle.net/ na parte html salva e manda o link deixa eu ver o padrao atual?

Comment: Blz, vou fazer isso! o texto é salvo no db apartir de um editor WYSIWYG! e talvez seja por isso né!

Comment: O link do jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8mn6eeq8/

Comment: desde já MUITO OBRIGADO @Virgilio Novic já me ajudou bem, me deu uma grande luz de como proceder

Comment: @OsvaldoQueta isso é. A falta de padrão e a sua duvida na pergunta está resolvida. Como você montou uma pergunta com um padrão tem que seguir nas resposta o mesmo. Ok? O texto do link esta sem padrão

Comment: @OsvaldoGueta sinalize então como resposta para a sua pergunta e se puder apagar os comentários é melhor

Answer (score 0):

Tente essa regex `(?<=\[\w{2}\-\w{2}\])(\.*)(?=\[\/\w{2}\-\w{2}\])`.

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar o seguinte código que irá retornar tanto para [pt-br] como para [en-us], ou qualquer outro tipo de valor entre os square brackets.

```
$re = '/\[[^]]+\]([^[]+)\[\/[^]]+\]/is';
$str = '[pt-br]

Qual é Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente texto manequim da impressão e composição indústria. Lorem Ipsum tem sido o texto padrão do manequim da indústria desde os anos 1500, quando uma impressora desconhecida tomou uma galera de tipo e mexidos-lo para fazer um livro tipo espécime. Ele sobreviveu não apenas cinco séculos, mas também o salto para composição eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Foi popularizado na década de 1960 com o lançamento de folhas Letraset contendo Lorem Ipsum passagens, e mais recentemente com software de editoração como Aldus PageMaker, incluindo versões de Lorem Ipsum.

[/pt-br]';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

// Retorna os valores encontrado
print_r($matches);
```

No seu caso irá encontrar 2 grupos, e no segundo está apenas o texto.
Ou seja, deve aceder a segunda posição do array.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal quando se captura conteúdo de marcação é ter o padrão da marcação em um grupo.

#### Exemplo

- Marcação `[pt-br][/pt-br]`, o padrão é o `pt-br`.
- Marcação `[en-us][/en-us]`, o padrão é o `en-us`.

Porque por isso em um grupo? Pois assim você usa a própria captura para identificar o final da marcação.

#### Resolução

`~\[([^]]+?)\](.*)\[/\1\]~s`

#### Explicação

- `\[([^]]+?)\]` - Temos o inicio da marcação que deve começar com `[` e terminar com `]` onde aplicamos a regra do grupo citada a cima.
- `(.*)` - Captura qualquer coisa, lembrando que como temos o modificador `s`, inclui o `\n`.
- `\[/\1\]` - Aqui é onde garante que vai parar na ocorrência do final marcação, pois deve capturar `[/` + marcação ja capturada no grupo1 (`\1`) + `]`

#### Problemas

- Segue a mesma ideia do HTML e o ideal para tratar estes casos é um parser, não regex.

Veja no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/DCnkMf/1)

Comment: bem, explicado valeu! mesmo todos você me ajudaram muito e acatei as sugestões de todos vocês, VALEU MESMO

Comment: Olá @Guilherme Lautert vc disse no seu post que: "o ideal para tratar estes casos é um parser, não regex." pode exemplificar? como você trataria esse problema dá um exemplo para mim por favor.

Comment: @OsvaldoQueta Aqui eu explico a questão do parses, que entraria no seu caso. O que quero disser é que teria de ser feito via programação e não REGEX, pois não seria possível tag que estiverem dentro da outra.